# Configure Domain Object Security (ACL) With Spring Security using couchbase db

Tags: java, spring-security, couchbase, acl

I am using spring with couchbase.I want to integrate Domain Object Security(ACL) provided by spring.
**Technology stack in my project:**
  SpringBoot,
  Spring 4.x,
  Couchbase Server 4.x - Using java sdk,
  Spring data Rest.
Please help me in providing code samples.

In my project we are only using couchbase no sql DB there is no schema based DB like oracle or mysql.

Thanks,
Ravindra

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is site is geared toward users ( you ) asking specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I wrote a Spring Security ACL to run on Neo4j (A NoSQL, Graph Database) which you can find in my [github](https://github.com/shazin/spring-security-acl-neo4j) which you can use as reference.

For your case though there is no out of the box solution. You will have to write your own implementation of Spring Security ACL for Couchbase. You just to write custom Couchbase implementations of the following;

1. LookupStrategy - Used to Read Acls based on Class Name and Instance
   Id
2. AclService - Non Mutable Acl related Services
3. MutableAclService - Mutable Acl related Services

Please have a look at `Neo4jLookupStrategy`, `Neo4jAclService` and `Neo4jMutableAclService` classes and the Tests for those.